Is there a way to provide socketTimeout for an r2dbc connection?
We recently had a situation where we use r2dbc connection pool for our spring boot application to connect to postgresql. This works fine most of the time but recently we have seen that whenever our database changes nodes, the open connections in the pool are just stuck in active mode and the pods are unable to serve requests for most of the services as they are unable to acquire a connection as the whole pool is already active and stuck. We have solved this issue for regular jdbc connection pools by setting the socketTimeout. I would like to know if there is anything similar for r2dbc pool or r2dbc. If not, then do you know of any other ways to prevent this issue?
Seems like nothing has changed in 3 years since this post
